# squid proxy client setup in linux machine

Tags: linux, proxy, redhat, squid, system-administration

What is the right setting for setting the squid proxy client in linux machine i followed the documentation to setup the export variable as following

```
bash $ export http_proxy="http://10.20.5.48:3128"   
bash $ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.228.197) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 922ms

bash $ export http_proxy="http://10.20.5.48:3128/" 
bash $ ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.123.110) 56(84) bytes of data.

bash $ export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.20.5.48:3128"
bash $ ping google.com                           
PING google.com (74.125.228.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1086ms

bash $ export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.20.5.48:3128/"
bash $ ping google.com                            
PING google.com (74.125.228.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1160ms
```

The squid server is running on port 3128 and reachable and no firewall or acl Issue with the squid.conf also

```
bash $ telnet 10.20.5.48 3128
Trying 10.20.5.48...
Connected to 10.20.5.48.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

When i change the yum.conf to use the proxy with the same server and IP the yum configuration work

Answer (score 0):

Ping not use http-proxy.
Try 
`GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com`
in your telnet session.